# Nintex fn-Substring For Pulling Out Variable Text

Tags: substring, nintex-workflow

I have a SharePoint list column that has its data formatted with `lastname, firstname`.  I'm trying to use `fn-SubString` to pull out the first name.  The problem is Nintex does not provide a function to give me a numeric count as to where the comma is.  I would like to use this as my starting position.

Is it possible to extract the first name in this example using the Nintex inline functions?

Andy

Answer (score 0):

There's an inline function you can install to get comma position:

http://www.vadimtabakman.com/nintex-workflow-instr-inline-function.aspx

Anyway, I think that using Nintex Workflow actions is easier. You just have to do the following:

1. Create a **Regular expression action**.
2. Set next pattern: **\w+,X (replace X by white space)**
3. Set operation: "**Replace text**"
4. Set your string in "Input text" section
5. Set a string variable to store `firstname` in "Store result in" section.

Another way (a bit longer):

1. Create a **Regular expression action**.
2. Set next pattern: **,X (replace X by white space)**
3. Set operation: "**Split**"
4. Set your string in "Input text" section
5. Set a collection variable to store result in "Store result in" section.
6. Create and use a **Collection operation action** to get last position of collection variable with `firstname`

I hope it helps! ;)